# <Plug> function failing, inserting as literal "<t_ý>S"

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

To autocomplete by pressing enter, I have the following map setup to work with neocomplete.vim:

```
inoremap <silent> <CR> <C-r>=<SID>my_cr_function()<CR>
function! s:my_cr_function()
  return pumvisible() ? "\<c-y>" : "\<CR>"
endfunction
```

This works fine.  To explain, `pumvisible()` returns true when neocomplete's PopUpMenu is showing.  `<c-y>` chooses the selected word, inserting it after the insert mode cursor, and closes the neocomplete popup.

I want to extend this mapping so that, when the autocompleted word is a "snippet" word, the neosnippet.vim plugin will automatically expand it.  This is what I tried:

```
inoremap <silent> <CR> <C-r>=<SID>my_cr_function()<CR>
function! s:my_cr_function()
  return pumvisible() ? "\<c-y>\<Plug>(neosnippet_expand_or_jump)" : "\<CR>"
endfunction
```

Instead of expanding the snippet word, this results in the following being inserted directly into the text where the cursor is:

```
<t_ý>S(neosnippet_expand_or_jump)`
```

How can I fix this and make it work?

*Possibly relevent note:* If I return to the working version of the code (first one above), hit "enter", then manually type `<C-k>` (while still in insert mode), the snippet expands correctly.  Here is the mapping setup for `<C-k>`:

```
imap <C-k> <Plug>(neosnippet_expand_or_jump)
```

Comment: Plug doesn't make sense in `inoremap` (and I have no idea what it does in the expression register) try using `imap <silent> <expr> <CR> <SID>my_cr_function()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<Plug>` doesn't make sense in `noremap` versions of commands since they themselves are mappings. So you should use `imap`. The second thing is you should be using expression mappings instead of the expression register if you want to execute the result of a mapping.

In total this looks like

```
imap <silent> <expr> <CR> <SID>my_cr_function()
```

You probably want to look at `:help :map-expression`