# <c-r>= versus <expr> in mappings

Tags: vim

I see both of these styles for inserting the contents of an expression in a map.  For example:

```
imap ,9 <c-r>=1+1<cr>
imap <expr> ,9 1+1
```

Both of these do the same thing as far as I can tell: they insert `2` if you type `,9` in insert mode.

I see some scripts use the first style and others the second.  Are there any differences?  It seems to me that the `<expr>` style is clearer, but are there use-cases where the `<c-r>=` style can accomplish something that `<expr>` can't?

Comment: These two examples are equivalent. You would want to use `<c-r>=` if you need to insert something in the middle of a mapping. (`<c-r>=` also can have different behavior http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487155/plug-function-failing-inserting-as-literal-t-%C3%BDs/34487571#34487571)

Comment: Thanks.  You can make it an answer and I'll accept it.  Could you include an example of using `<c-r>=` to insert something in the middle of a mapping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your two examples are equivalent. You should prefer the second style as `<c-r>=` behaves differently in some case. One recent example would be  [<Plug> function failing, inserting as literal "<t_ý>S"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34487155/1890567), where using `<c-r>=<Plug>Func()<CR>` did something different and unexpected compared to `<Plug>Func()` in an expression mapping.

Most of the uses for `<c-r>=` should be when you want to insert the result of the expression in the middle of your mapping (or just using the expression register manually). A trivial example would be you want to include the contents of the `g:some_var` variable in between parentheses when you hit `,8`

```
imap ,8 (<c-r>=g:some_var<cr>)
```

Answer (score 4):

My biggest issues with `:map-<expr>` are the one explained in the documentation:

- We cannot modify the buffer, nor play with other buffers
- We cannot use `:normal`
- We cannot move the cursor around (as an observable property of the mapping) -- which I sometime do with `:normal`...

Moreover, `i_CTRL-R` has been around for a much longer time. As a consequence I haven't even try to migrate my old, and intensively tested and used, mappings to `i(nore)map <expr>`.